# Change fixed links color depending on background

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want my side fixed links to change their color on scroll, depending on background color. If background is white - then change links color to #000, else #fff.
I tried CSS *mixed-blend-mode: difference*, but there is no option to control the color. So I want to make it with jquery. How can I make it?

Here is my code example

```css
.right-aside {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    right: -10px;
    top: 100px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
    height: fit-content;
    }
.right-aside__menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.right-aside__menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 300ms;
    color: #fff;
}

.left-aside {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    left: -10px;
    top: 100px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
    }
.left-aside__menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.left-aside__menu ul li a {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 300ms;
    color: #fff;
}
.left-aside__menu-item-link .uk-icon {
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-width: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper div {
  height: 50vh;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<aside class="right-aside">
<nav class="right-aside__menu">
<ul class="right-aside__menu-list">

<li class="right-aside__menu-item ">
<a href="" class="right-aside__menu-item-link" title="phone">
<span class="right-aside__menu-icon">

</span>
<span class="phone-vertical">+7 777 777 77 77</span>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>

</aside>    
    <aside class="left-aside">
<nav class="left-aside__menu">
<ul class="left-aside__menu-list">

<li class="left-aside__menu-item ">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="left-aside__menu-item-link" title="contacts">
<span uk-icon="icon: instagram"></span>
<span class="phone-vertical">instagramaccount</span>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>

</aside>
```

Comment: i have done this on a button but would love to see it work here. function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myP2").style.color = "green"; 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.aside-link').each(function(){
    var fixed = $(this);

    var fixed_position = $(".aside-link").offset().top;
    var fixed_height = $(".aside-link").height();

    var addClass = false;
    $('.white').each(function(){

        var toCross_position = $(this).offset().top;
        var toCross_height = $(this).height();

        if (fixed_position + fixed_height  < toCross_position) {
            //fixed.removeClass('white');
        } else if (fixed_position > toCross_position + toCross_height) {
            //fixed.removeClass('white');
        } else {
            addClass = true;
        }
    });
    if(addClass == true){
        fixed.addClass('dark');
    }else{
        fixed.removeClass('dark');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.right-aside {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    right: -10px;
    top: 100px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
    height: fit-content;
    }
.right-aside__menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.right-aside__menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 300ms;
    color: #fff;
}

.left-aside {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    left: -10px;
    top: 100px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
    }
.left-aside__menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.left-aside__menu ul li a {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 300ms;
    color: #fff;
}
.left-aside__menu-item-link .uk-icon {
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-width: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper div {
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: green;
}
.aside-link.dark {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div class="white" id="test"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<aside class="right-aside">
<nav class="right-aside__menu">
<ul class="right-aside__menu-list">

<li class="right-aside__menu-item ">
<a href="" class="right-aside__menu-item-link aside-link" title="phone">
<span class="right-aside__menu-icon">

</span>
<span class="phone-vertical">+7 777 777 77 77</span>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>

</aside>    
    <aside class="left-aside">
<nav class="left-aside__menu">
<ul class="left-aside__menu-list">

<li class="left-aside__menu-item ">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="left-aside__menu-item-link aside-link" title="contacts">
<span uk-icon="icon: instagram"></span>
<span class="phone-vertical">instagramaccount</span>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>

</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add scroll listener to your document and use codes below:

```
$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 50) {
    // After the user reaches to position, this code will change text color.
    $("element").addClass("blackColor");
  } else {
    $("element").removeClass("whiteColor");
  }
});
```

Comment: Please edit and place in snippet i cant get this to work